# In PHP does max_execution_time affect shutdown functions that are run through a register_shutdown_function() call?

Tags: php, shutdown, execution-time, shutdown-hook, executiontimeout

I have a shutdown function registered using `register_shutdown_function()` that takes a long time to complete. Will PHP's `max_execution_time` cause PHP to terminate this function or will it run until it completes or errors out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will run to completion.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php#33575